# How to pass dictionary object value in mysql query as argument?

Tags: python, mysql

I am getting the list of customers `[{'id': 31L}, {'id': 35L}]` and in select query how to pass id as argument?

**query**

```
for customer in customer_list:
      "select * from base_order where location_id=%s and city='Hyderabad'", (customer['id'])
```

But it is giving error **TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects**

Comment: The loop you posted is correct Python syntax, and it doesn't throw any errors, but it doesn't do anything at all.  It just creates a tuple in each iteration, and then ignores that tuple.  I suspect your actual code is different from what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting quotes around the ids to make each one a string? ie. '31L'